# "event" is deprecated while creating a handler to select filters in React. What can I use instead?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling, event-listener

I am creating an expense tracker, and I am adding a component to filter expenses by year. While creating the handler function thats listens for changes in the  element, I get a warning and a strikethrough across "event", because it states that the "event" parameter I passed to the handler function is deprecated.

I have several other events in the app for functions that listen for changes in  elements. What is the problem then? Is it because I cannot use "event" for  elements?

This is what I have so far (I need to still implement props to import data and state changes), but in the image attached you can notice the error message and that "event" has a strikethrough. At this stage it should have been working or at least not showing the error message.

````
import { React, useState } from 'react';

import './ExpensesFilter.css';

//Listen to dropdown change and selected year is then forwarded to the Expenses component, 
//there you store it in a state
const ExpensesFilter = () => { 
  
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(" ")  

  const dropdownChangeHandler = (event) = {
    console.log(event.target.value)
  };

  return (
    <div className='expenses-filter'>
      <div className='expenses-filter__control'>
        <label>Filter by year</label>
        <select onChange={dropdownChangeHandler}>
          <option value='2022'>2022</option>
          <option value='2021'>2021</option>
          <option value='2020'>2020</option>
          <option value='2019'>2019</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExpensesFilter;```
````

Comment: Possible typo: `dropdownChangeHandler` is not correctly defined, missing the "fat arrow" (`=>`), `const dropdownChangeHandler = (event) => {`

Comment: It is indeed the above mentioned typo.  The code is still syntactically valid with that typo (though doesn't do the same thing), but relies on the window-level `event` symbol, which is what the warning is indicating.  Fix the typo and `event` becomes simply the name of the function argument.

Answer (score 1):

you have a syntax error in your function.
It should be

```js
const dropdownChangeHandler = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.value);
};
```